# comparar dos strings en python

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer un código para comparar dos líneas de strings y quería pedir alguna sugerencia

me entregan dos líneas de strings, la primera es una lista de compra de artículos y la segunda corresponden a los artículos disponibles en la tienda, cada una en un formato de: articulo,cantidad;articulo2,cantidad. Por ejemplo:

Ejemplo 1
línea 1 = clavos,5;martillo,1
línea 2 = llaves,7;clavos,3;destornillador,4

Ejemplo 2

línea 1 = pintura,3;alicate,1;,rastrillo,3
línea 2 = clavos,5;pintura,5;alicate,4;rastrillo,2

Debo ver si los artículos de la línea 1 se encuentran disponibles en la línea 2 y si queda stock suficiente en la tienda

He pensado varias formas de hacerlo como pasarlo a lista e ir iterando para comparar pero se me hace complejo ver como comparo correctamente el stock de un articulo de la línea 1 con el stock del mismo articulo de la línea 2.

Más que nada pido si es que tienen alguna sugerencia de como podría realizarlo, si es posible, utilizando funciones básicas que no sea importando alguna función especial ya que quiero aprender a realizarlo con lo que he aprendido hasta ahora como ciclos, listas, strings, etc. De antemano agradezco al que quiera ayudar

Comment: mejor muestra lo que has intentado, pues si pides recomendaciones tu pregunta acabara cerrada ya que este sitio no es para pedir sugerencias ni recomendaciones, ademas al no mostrar nada se puede pensar que quieres que hagamos tu tarea

Comment: no era tarea amigo solo quería aprender a comparar strings :/. Pensé que si se podían pedir sugerencias, lo siento de todas formas

Comment: no te preocupes, como dije puedes añadir las formas en que dices que haz intentado y con mucho gusto te ayudaremos

Comment: Evita hacer preguntas que pidan sugerencias. En su lugar, pone lo que hiciste, o las versiones de las cosas que hiciste por lo menos.

Comment: @Mario creo que no hacia falta retirar toda la información de tu pregunta, pues así no se entiende nada y mas parece una tarea, esto no ayudara a otras personas

Comment: @Christian primero me dijiste que no era un sitio para pedir recomendaciones, ¿ahora  te molesta que retire la pregunta?, segundo, Dije que no era tarea, pero ¿y si lo fuera ? Nunca te pedí específicamente a ti que me ayudaras, si te molesta simplemente no respondes y ya , no tienes que andar como dueño del sitio recriminando a quienes formulan mal las preguntas o se equivocan respondiendo, agradezco a los que tuvieron la voluntad de simplemente ayudar, y agradezco de igual forma a los que no quisieron ayudar y simplemente no respondieron.

Comment: @Christian Por que no le encuentro la idea a andar buscando en la página y respondiendo a ver si te parece o no lo que preguntan las otras personas

Comment: @Mario de igual forma pides una recomendación cuando dices *"... quería pedir alguna sugerencia"*, otra cosa es que no importa si fuese tarea o no solo que si no investigas nada prácticamente vienes diciendo que te resuelvan el problema. Finalmente solo doy recomendaciones para que las preguntas este bien formuladas y asi otras personas puedan solucionar su problema, asi es como se aporta a la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, no vandalices tu pregunta ya que ese tipo de actos no aporta nada a la comunidad. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Existe un [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) que has aceptado seguir al crear una cuenta en [es.so]. Saludos

Comment: @Mario por desgracia tu pregunta fue cerrada, recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con listas y diccionarios se te hace muy sencillo.

```
lista_compra = (clavos,5;martillo,1).split(';')
almacen = (llaves,7;clavos,3;destornillador,4).split(';')
```

luego pasas cada par de datos a un diccionario con la estructura

```
artículo{nombre: cantidad}
```

Todo junto sería algo parecido a esto:

```
lista = inventario.split(';')
    for i in lista:
        dato = i.split(',')
        invent[dato[0]] = int(dato[1]) # Importante pasar a número
```

***edito para añadir crear diccionarios por comprensión.***

El ciclo for anterior se puede sustituir por:

```
inventario = {arti.split( ',' )[0]: int( arti.split( ',' )[1] ) for arti in invent.split( ';' )}
```

Con esta estructura es muy sencillo,

```
for articulo in almacen

    if articulo not in inventario

    if lista_compra[articulo] > inventario[articulo]
```

Algo muy muy parecido lo tienes en esta pregunta, seguramente te sirva para empezar y así poder luego preguntar dudas: [crear dos funciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/459945/crear-dos-funciones/460245#460245)
Tienes 2 opciones todo hecho con cadenas y otra con listas y diccionarios.

Comment: Buenas, por favor editala, por que ha sido marcada para revision, y podría ser borrada al no ser una respuesta. Te recomiendo leer [answer] para mas info.

Answer (score -1):

Pues una de las formas que se me ocurre es que te crees un diccionario donde la llave sea el nombre del producto y el valor sea la cantidad de stock!

Ejemplo:
linea1 = clavos,5;martillo,1

El diccionario se vería similar a:

productos = {
'clavos': 5,
'martillo': 1
}

Comment: Y como se crea el diccionario? por favor mira [answer].. que tu respuesta sea completa...